# Large Scale App - Choosing the right database, and serving data from it

Tags: database, google-app-engine, design-patterns, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I have been doing a lot of research recently non-stop. I know this is a vague question, but I will try be as specific as I can. I have been developing small to medium web systems for a while, but never dealt with noSQL databases, or made something with this scale. The purpose of the question is to make the right decision, as I don't want to shoot myself in the foot. And hopefully it can help someone else like me, new to this and a specific example can clarify more things
in my opinion.

To make this easier, I will give an example very close to what I'm trying to achieve, which is very simple and covers a lot of similar systems out there. Hopefully by this example I will clear out the type of data I'm dealing with, the kind of system, and operations that need to be performed.

**Example System Overview**

1) System Overview: Let's say we are dealing with a multi-tenant system, that allows users to track traffic to specific pages on their sites. The user/customer needs to plant a code of my system into their page, and this code, will call a service on my server that simply stores the data in the database. The data is simply the page visitor's data, stuff like the page they visited, browser, device, time of visit..etc. Here, the data is **STORED**

2) The users/customers can login to the system, and view their data. Here the data is **SERVED**

3) In addition to storing, and serving data, there's another service in the system, which will be processing this data. And finding patterns/conclusions about the site visitors. For example, specific page, is more visited via mobile devices.. (and do whatever with this conclusion). Here the data is **PROCESSED**

4) We are talking about Large volumes of data. Probably starts with 3-4 Million writes per day (visits), and I want to be sure it can scale up to Billion+

**Question 1:**

Now, I have been cracking my head over Google Cloud Solutions. I thought that it's best to go with App Engine, since I can't afford to maintain a virtual server. I decided to go with the DataStore and here comes my question:

**1) Is DataStore the most appropriate solution for this case?**

According to my research, I found that datastore is most appropriate, but of course I'm not 100% confident due to my lack of experience. But I chose this because I come from using SQL a lot. I didn't go for Cloud SQL, because my data is not that relational, and due to the volume and the need of reliability and scalability of my system, I thought a NoSQL solution would be better. Datastore has GQL syntax, which is similar to SQL querying language. Properties of objects are also indexed. I will probably need to read/filter data by Device type for example. I also saw that BigTable is very different (probably not used to it), and all data you have is Key:Value, where I think it's not possible/hard to query by specific property for example?

Eventhough I don't believe my data is really structured. Specially that I will be using Namespaces for users/customers (multi-tenant), and it's automatically included in the key. The entities I have at the moment is User (will probably include few entities under it), and Visit as a "standalone" entity.

**Question 2**

**What's the best practice for serving data to customers?**

I don't want to show customers Millions of visits. I would give them overall stats. For example how many visits via Android Mobile Devices. Or stats within Time-Range. So I believe there are 2 approaches. First, make separate database. Or maybe separate entity within the same DataStore, that holds total daily stats per customer. And then make serving by adding up "days stats" which doesn't feel right. Second, Every time I want to serve data, I make a query to the one big database. But also the second approach doesn't feel right. Because as I know, Datastore doesn't have "Group by" functionality for example, or aggregates. So every time, a customer wants to see stats "by device" I need to make the "group by" functionality by code on memory? or if I just want to display the "count" of specific filter query result, which is not directly supported with datastore I believe? Also making these calculations in real time when serving the data sounds like a lot.

Now I know there's a solution called BigQuery by Google, which I believe does what I want and allows me to serve the data I want to customers with high flexibility and efficiency, but as I understood it works only on datastore "backups", I need to serve data in real time.

---

I appreciate a lot anyone taking the time to give any input on the matter. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Scalability is achievable with the right app design. However you say that `I can't afford to maintain a virtual server` - which could be an issue: GAE costs can become significant when "large scale" kicks in, often way above the costs of regular VMs (you pay the price for scalable PaaS convenience). In fact switching to VMs has been reported as one approach for reducing costs of large scale apps. So I'd start here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing.

Comment: Well, if I don't pay it to Google, I will have to pay it to someone else to maintain/manage that for me. As I said I'm not experienced enough, but as far as I have researched, I understood that the Database design is the bigger factor. And either case, I will take your point into consideration and investigate it further. but either way, I need to make a decision about the database design. If I'm going for VM, or App Engine.

Comment: Also the purpose of the question is clarifications about dealing with large data sets in NoSQL Data Structure (Choosing the right database, and how to serve it in real time), regardless if I'm going for App Engine, or Compute Engine.

Comment: You post may be closed as off-topic - too broad/opinion based. But there are tons of related posts out there: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[gae-datastore]+scale.

Comment: I started my first software company 17 years ago - servers + SQL database, of course. I will never start any new project (of any size) on anything other than a PaaS like App Engine (or IaaS only when I have to, e.g. file streaming is not supported by App Engine). If you do it right, you can even stay within the free quota until your project really takes off.

Comment: IBMs Bluemix could be another option. It's scalable, highly customizable, and has a free quota. Given your large and scalable data requirements their DB2 database service might be worth looking into, however DB2 is relational. In any case Bluemix allows you to use your own custom services. --Disclaimer-- I work for IBM

Answer (score 0):

I built a similar system several years ago using MongoDB on Amazon AWS. This year, tired of doing DevOps on AWS (nod to @AndreiVolgin), I've moved it to Google BigQuery.

Datastore for my use case was overkill and frankly, limiting. I would have wanted to turn off indexes for most attributes anyways to save on storage cost. Limiting because it's harder to hook up datastore-based data with a visualization tool such as Tableau.

Regarding

> I know there's a solution called BigQuery by Google, which I
>   believe does what I want and allows me to serve the data I want to
>   customers with high flexibility and efficiency, but as I understood it
>   works only on datastore "backups", I need to serve data in real time.

When my system receives a datum, page visitor data in your example, it [streams it directly to BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). So no, it doesn't only work on backups. Whether you can use it to report "real time" depends on what real time means to you. My system computes aggregate statistics once every couple hours for presentation to users.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is DataStore the most appropriate solution for this case?

Like you, I came from a SQL background when starting out with datastore. Datastore is really different from SQL. You kind of have to think in a totally different way. It is not the opposite of SQL, it is just, totally different.

It is hard to answer your question 1, because in theory, the only person qualified to answer that question is you. We cannot possibly know or anticipate all the requirements you have and will have.

That being said, in my experience (and from what other people say too), anything you can accomplish with SQL, you can do accomplish Datastore - just keep in mind that it is going to be different from what you are used to and you might need to get creative in some places. However, like me, you recognize that the ability to scale and all the automation that comes with App Engine is worth the effort. It's also kind of fun.

> 2. What's the best practice for serving data to customers?

Sounds like you just have one type of data. I would have one entity and just have an enum property on it "MOBILE", "WEB", etc. and then just filter by that:

```
Query<SomeEntity> q = ofy().load().type(SomeEntity.class).filter("platformType =", "MOBILE_ANDROID");
for (SomeEntity someEntity: q) {
    System.out.println(someEntity.toString());
}
```

See more in official docs: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries